# Reading whole S3 bucket in one request

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

i have a bucket with 100,000 images(png\jpg) and i want to read them all in one s3 request.
this is my code:

```
# geting connection to s3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

# geting list of all objectsummery in the relevant dir - this is a request to the api
crops_path_list = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix)

# iterating on the list and geting objects
for index, crop in enumerate(crops_path_list):
    # getting the bytes from s3 - this a request to the api
    crop = crop.get()

    # working with the bytes to make them image
    image_content = crop['Body'].read()
    bytes_images = BytesIO(image_content)
    image = Image.open(bytes_images)
    image = image.convert("RGB")
    image = np.asarray(image)
    image = np.ascontiguousarray(image.transpose(2, 0, 1))
    image  = torch.from_numpy(np.array(image)).unsqueeze(0).to(dtype=torch.float32, device=device)

    # adding to list of all images
    images.append(image)
```

it takes agessss because every `.get()` is a request to the api. could not find any use to get the whole `crops_path_list` list in one request. other then running threads\subprocess\ziping, any other ideas how to use less IO and api requests?

thanks :)

Comment: You could download the files to the local disk (either on an EC2 instance or your computer) using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (which does it quickly via multithreading). Then, you could run your code on local files, which should be faster.

Comment: need to support docker containers, so unfortenatly this is not an option :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PySpark works great for me, solved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about how you used PySpark to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Downloading each file is a request.

Comment: so if i want to make it faster working with s3 only multi threading is an option?

Comment: @BennySemyonov Multithreading is a good option. S3 has basically unlimited bandwidth, so you can download files as fast as your internet can go.